# How perf_event_open syscall detects attached process exits like "perf record -p <pid> command exits when <pid> process exits"?

Tags: linux, perf

I want to dynamically attach a process to be monitored using perf_event_open syscall, but when the monitored process exits, the perf_event_open syscall calling process cannot detects it. Any solution for this? Thanks.